# Pass columns numbers using Javascript for google charts plots

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have CSV data in the following format:

```
Customer , Key1 , Key2 , Key 3 , Key4 , Sum , Total 
 GOOGLE, 101 ,6 , 3, 2, 6, 100 ,121
 AAPLE , 12 ,12,34,21,4,66,112
```

I just need columns Customer , Key1 , Key2 , Key 3 , Key4 need to exclude Sum , Total

Can someone help me in google charts how do i do that?

```html
<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
        callback: function () {
         $.get("failures.csv", function(csvString) {
         var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
         console.log(arrayData);
         var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data);
    });
  },
   packages: ['corechart']
   });
   </script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: arrayData.forEach((activity) => {  

   activity.pop(8);

   });

   arrayData.pop(8);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a data view, use hide columns method, then draw chart with data view...

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);  // <-- new keyword not needed here

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.hideColumns([5, 6]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view);
```

or you can use the set columns method, to specify which columns to use...

```
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```